Moving the legend to the bottom of pie chart and re-arranging text in Y-axis (bar chart)
For the pie chart:
Looking to place the legend at the bottom of the pie chart instead of the default setting which is to the right of the pie chart.
For the bar chart:
Also, how to re-arrange the Y axis ? The underlying values are formatted as texts. Need to move 18-24mths to the top - in the following sequence.
0-18mths
18-24mths
24-36mths

36mths

Aging (months)
By customer
